# Cross Tab or Pivot query in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can someone please help me with a cross tab/pivot query in SQL 2005

Given Data looks like

```
EmpId   OrgId  DayCt  Cost

1       20     15     100

2       20     36     300

3       40     25     200

4       40     10     50
```

Result to be like:

```
EmpId       OrgId 20          OrgId 40  

         DayCt  Cost          DayCt  Cost


1         15     100

2         36     300

3                             25     200

4                             10     50
```

EmpId in 1st Col and then Org Ids in the next col. But under every OrgId, I want DayCt & Cost also to be included as sub columns. Not sure if this is doable. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide desired results for your example data?

Comment: Thanks for a quick look. No matter what I do but cant get formatting right here. Let me try again.

Comment: To lay out tables use spaces as you already did, then you just need to select the table and hit the `{}` icon in the toolbar so it is treated as code and the spaces don't get collapsed down in one.

Comment: Hey thanks for the formatting tip.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as sub columns this seems like something that should be done in your application/reporting tool.

This is about the closest you can get in SQL

```
;WITH T(EmpId,OrgId,DayCt,Cost) AS
(
select 1, 20,  15,  100 UNION ALL
select 2, 20,  36,  300 UNION ALL
select 3, 40,  25,  200 UNION ALL
select 4, 40,  10,  50
)
SELECT EmpId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN OrgId =20 THEN DayCt END) AS [OrgId 20 DayCt],
       MAX(CASE WHEN OrgId =20 THEN Cost END) AS [OrgId 20 Cost],
       MAX(CASE WHEN OrgId =40 THEN DayCt END) AS [OrgId 40 DayCt],
       MAX(CASE WHEN OrgId =40 THEN Cost END) AS [OrgId 40 Cost]
FROM T
GROUP BY EmpId
```

Returns

```
EmpId       OrgId 20 DayCt OrgId 20 Cost OrgId 40 DayCt OrgId 40 Cost
----------- -------------- ------------- -------------- -------------
1           15             100           NULL           NULL
2           36             300           NULL           NULL
3           NULL           NULL          25             200
4           NULL           NULL          10             50
```

Comment: Sorry about this but I have abt a 100 OrgIds, does it mean I have to type all of them in the query with all possible combinations of DayCt and Cost?

Comment: @KIA - Yes. There is no SQL Server function that does this for you. If the `OrgId`s aren't static then you would need dynamic SQL to generate the above (google "dynamic pivot")

Comment: @KIA: How are you going to display them? @Martin: +1, btw.

Comment: @KIA: Yes but... 100 columns? with 2 sub-columns each? It's not even the question whether it can fit on the screen, but rather whether it will be easy to work with a grid with so many columns. But well, you should know better. Without knowing more details, I might be exaggerating the problem.